# Notification action buttons not appearing on iOS and android using one signal react-native-onsignal

Tags: react-native, onesignal

I'm trying to send notifications with action buttons. The notifications arrive and work perfectly - however actions do not appear on either android (7.0) or iOS (11.2.1)

I am sending this body with the post request to https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications | I even tried the OS UI dashboard tool and nothing worked.

```
{
    "app_id": "#########-#########-########",
    "heading": "OneSignal Web Push Notification",
    "contents": {
        "en": "Action buttons increase the ways your users can interact with your notification."
    },
    "data": {
        "notificationType": "news-feature"
    },
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "icon": "https://onesignal.com/images/notification_logo.png",
    "buttons": [
        {
            "action": "like-button",
            "title": "Like",
            "icon": "http://i.imgur.com/N8SN8ZS.png",
            "url": "https://example.com"
        },
        {
            "action": "read-more-button",
            "title": "Read more",
            "icon": "http://i.imgur.com/MIxJp1L.png",
            "url": "https://example.com"
        }
    ],
    "action": "like-button",
    "include_player_ids": [
        "######-###################-#####", //iOS ID
        "######-###################-#####", // android ID
    ]
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to solve or debug this?

Comment: Ok, I spent a good 4 hours trying to figure this out. I had everything set up correctly, but I was sending my notifications with a category. I don't know exactly why this was causing an issue for me but I get the action buttons and images if I don't send a category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up the OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension in order for buttons (as well as images, etc) to appear in push notifications fixed the problem.

iOS Xcode Project guide is helpful in this matter:

https://github.com/Nightsd01/react-native-onesignal#add-notification-service-extension

A small pointer to skip the part where you have to `pod install` the onesignal pod for the app target. Just install the ServiceExtension pod.

---

For Android updating the payload of the buttons object in the POST request fixed the problem.

`{
    "app_id": "######-###################-#####",
    "heading": "OneSignal Web Push Notification",
    "contents": {
        "en": "Action buttons increase the ways your users can interact with your notification."
    },
    "data": {
        "notificationType": "news-feature"
    },
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "icon": "https://onesignal.com/images/notification_logo.png",
    "buttons":[
        {"id": "id1", "text": "button1", "icon": "ic_launcher"}, 
        {"id": "id2", "text": "button2", "icon": "ic_launcher"}
    ],
    "action": "like-button",
    "include_player_ids": [
        "######-###################-#####", // iOS ID
        "######-###################-#####" // android ID
    ]
}`